# Could someone please explain sin, cos, and tan in a simple way?

Tags: geometry, physics

I haven't taken this in school yet but I love math and physics and join lots of competitions. I have a problem with sine, cosine, and tangent, that I really need a SIMPLE explanation along with an example. I know for a first that they are related to angles and are used in physics, so how are they calculated and how are they used?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why a downvote for such a valuable question ? Everyone was once a beginner.

Comment: There are loads of resources online. For example: https://byjus.com/maths/trigonometric-functions/

or https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/trigonometry.html

Comment: Also, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometry.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I wouldn't downvote it, but I'm tempted to close-vote for being too broad / needs more focus.

Comment: I would mark up your comments guys.. thank you so much

Comment: @PM2Ring I specifically stated that I want the definition and example for each of sin, cos and tan. How much narrower can this get

Comment: This is a big, important question! It deserves a whole book, not just a Stack Exchange answer. But anyway, have you studied similar triangles?

Comment: Yes @PM2Ring I did

Comment: You can get the definitions from the Wikipedia link, more specifically https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometry#Trigonometric_ratios If you have problems understanding what's there, edit the details of what's unclear or confusing into your question, and we'll try to address those details.

Comment: Excellent. The trig ratios are just a neat way of handling similar triangles, starting with right angle triangles.

Comment: @PM2Ring thanks a lot, I have checked from some of the sources others listed above and I got it

Comment: @PM2Ring: I agree with you, but how can one ask for introductory information on a discipline, then ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Fair point. It can be hard to learn new topics from scratch using Stack Exchange or Wikipedia. I think that what happened here is good, though. The OP asked a "Needs focus" question, we gave a few relevant links & asked questions to help narrow the focus, *and the OP responded* by checking the links & replying to our queries. The question has gathered a couple of close votes, but it's (currently) still open. ;)

Comment: @PM2Ring: yep, and we have a "happy end".

Comment: Thanks to everyone who participated here. Cant tell u how much it all helped

Comment: @YvesDaoust Indeed we do! But note that your answer is of limited use to someone who hasn't learned about similar triangles, so eliciting that from Aya was fairly important.

Comment: See my recent answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3881332) to a similar question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is all about triangles and relations between the side lengths and angle amplitudes.

In a right triangle, by definition,

$$\cos(\theta)=\frac AC$$

$$\sin(\theta)=\frac BC$$

$$\tan(\theta)=\frac BA$$

[image]

Using these three interrelated functions, you can solve a real lot of geometric problems, such as relations between angles and sides of a general triangle, or even a triangle drawn on a sphere, and do topography, mechanics, geography, GPS, optics, astronomy... and more.

It turns out that these functions also have a deep meaning in maths and they are about as essential as the four basic operations and exponentiation. But this is an advanced topic.

To compute them, calculators have built-in algorithms, mostly based on approximation polynomials. E.g., for an angle expressed in radians,

$$\cos(\theta)\approx1-\frac{\theta^2}2+\frac{\theta^4}{4!}-\frac{\theta^6}{6!}+\cdots$$

and the more terms you add, the closer you get to the exact value.

---

Amazingly, to solve the apparently innocuous equation

$$4x^3-3x=\frac13,$$
you need the trigonometric functions.

Comment: I think your tangent might be a it off there! Great answer otherwise.

Comment: @TyJensen: ooops, getting an F (despite double checking :-( ). Thanks for the notice.

Comment: source for the "amazingly" thing?

Comment: You don't *have* to use trigonometric functions to solve that, but they certainly produce a much nicer and easier solution than Cardano's method.

Comment: @PaulSinclair: sorry, you do have. This is a *casus irreductibilis* that needs cubic roots of complex numbers. These cannot be obtained without the trigonometric functions. The famous angle trisection.

Comment: @user253751: $\cos3\theta=\dfrac13$, there is no better way.