# Definition of $\sin()$, $\cos()$ and $\tan()$

Tags: trigonometry

This is just a clear up of what I just learnt.

Imagine a right triangle where $a$ and $b$ are the legs and $c$ is the hypotenuse. $\alpha$ is the angle between $a$ (the short side) and $c$. Is it *always* true that:
\begin{align*}
\sin(\alpha) & = \frac{b}{c}\\[2mm]
\cos(\alpha) & = \frac{a}{c}\\[2mm]
\tan(\alpha) & = \frac{b}{a}
\end{align*}

Because it seems to me that it is awfully specific to have that rule, and is there any proof that it is true? I just want to clear it up so I can move on. (I'm self-taught so there is no specific lesson, take your time)

Thanks in advance,
Alex

Comment: How do you *define* $\sin$, $\cos$, and $\tan$?

Comment: [This might help you.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3892285/could-someone-please-explain-sin-cos-and-tan-in-a-simple-way)

Comment: That's kind of like asking if it's always true that $a^2=a\times a$.

Comment: With those definitions, it's *not* true that $a$ is always the short side. In fact, for $0\le\alpha<45°$, $a>b$.

Comment: @PM2Ring: But if $a$ is the short side, $\alpha$ will always be $\ge 45°$.

Comment: @TonyK Well sure, but "trigonometry for angles between 45° and 90°" seems awfully specific. ;)

Comment: @PM2Ring: So the OP's equations _are_ true. Agreed?

Comment: @TonyK Yes, the equations are true, I never disputed that. I was just pointing out the problem of insisting that $a$ is the short leg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the definition for sin, cos and tan in the context of right triangles. Definitions are, by definition, always true. You can think it as a way to assign the same thing by a shorter name. So instead of write b/c all the time, you can write sin(alpha) instead, and vice versa.

It seems superfluous, but once the ideas of sine and cosine extends to all real numbers, it becomes very beautiful and powerful.